# Most Wanted Features for Websites

Tags: web-applications

I'm trying to identify what would be the best selling point for a set of articles I'm writing. Should I cover RSS feeds or Facebook/Twitter/YouTube integration into a web site? Or something else? I'm already covering Image galleries, blogs, forums, polls, (and even shopping carts). I apologize if this is too subjective. I just want to know what you are most often requested to create for client websites.

EDIT: Let me put it this way. Say you are learning how to build websites in PHP. You want to get clients as quickly as possible, so which would you learn how to do first: RSS feeds from other sites, or grabbing data from 3rd party sites, like Facebook and Twitter, or integrating YouTube videos? What would likely get you a client first? Something else? (beyond blogs, forums, polls, image galleries, and shopping carts)

Comment: Why would you want to create a product that everyone else is selling right now?  Haven't you heard of "little fish in a big pond"?  If you want to make money, you need a unique selling proposition.

Comment: Sorry, by "writing" I mean writing about how to program them, not writing as in programming them. I'm looking for topics.

Comment: You may consider making this a wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would vote for RSS, Twitter, Widgets (such as Google Maps as already suggested), and YouTube. RSS and Twitter give you dynamic content and if it's for a physical business or establishment, Google Map integration is great if it lets people find directions without having to leave your website, giving the business more "face time" with customers instead of having them visit a 3rd party link to find directions.

The two largest things I think are missing from your list are database integration and security. With lots of websites now having databases in the GB or larger to serve content, having a decent grasp of how to use PHP to read/write information from a database would be a good thing to be exposed to sooner rather than later. In addition, I would also address the need to build secure admin controls and how to handle private information securely (usernames, passwords, email etc.), especially if you are going to be talking about using shopping carts.

Answer (score 3):

Surely this depends on your web application and what it does?

Who is your target audience and how will you generate revenue, and who are you selling it to?

All of these questions are critical for determining which features to develop.

Relating to your edit, I would say focus on the content, and functionality specific to your website. What is it's core reason for existing?

Creating a website for learning using PHP, doesn't really mean it is worth anything, except to you. (Unless it is possibly explaining how to code PHP?)

Answer (score 2):

People love seeing a Google maps widget in their site. You put the neat stuff like a bubble dialogue box saying what it is and how to get directions to there. So I guess this would fall under, adding widgets to a site.

e.g. http://www.stjamestheapostle.ca/home/mapdirections/

Comment: I won't answer twice so I will just append it in a comment. I think knowing how to set up Google Analytics and other Google webmaster tools, http://www.google.com/webmasters/, would be a good thing to know to help clients' SEO as well as seeing which content on their site is popular. Also Google's AdSense integrated into a web site is good to know too if you're doing blogs.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for RSS feeds from other sites,
Usually a site with very little new things, looks much more dynamic by adding this.